# How to add the chart of "voltage fluctuations per core" in Netdata monitoring the status of Raspberry Pi 3A+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, monitoring, health-monitoring, real-time-data, netdata

I am monitoring the status of my RPi 3A+ while running different applications on the Pi via Netdata monitoring agent.
I want to study about the variations in the per core voltage while executing a particular application on netdata .

I followed the instructions given in the page:
https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/collectors/charts.d.plugin/sensors

But after restarting netdata, I am not abe to see the voltage chart addition.

I'd really appreciate the help

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The doc that you linked is obsolete. Use https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/collectors/python.d.plugin/sensors , meaning you should configure `python.d/sensors.conf`

This said, charts should be generated dynamically, so I would check your netdata error.log for any problems and make sure you are running the latest version.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your response? The above link to modify python file doesn't show what changes are supposed to be made to enable the required voltage charts. Also how am i supposed to access my error log file, i'm not sure.

Comment: use cd /var/log/netdata

there 7 files in it namely 
access.log 
access.log.1 
access.log.2.gz 
debug.log 
error.log 
error.log.1 
error.log.2.gz

And no file i'm able to open.

I get an error:

root@raspberrypi:~# cd /var/log/netdata/error.log
bash: cd: /var/log/netdata/error.log: Not a directory

Comment: Not too familiar with what's available on the Pi, but try to `cat` the file to see the file's contents, i.e. `cat /var/log/netdata/error.log`